# Migrate static site to Wordpress, or should I use other CMS system?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want the design to look exactly like the old even though it's [ugly and uses frames](http://www.eddaconsult.se):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Untitled Document</TITLE>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</HEAD>

<FRAMESET rows="70,1*" cols="*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0"> 
  <FRAMESET cols="660,*" rows="*"> 
    <FRAME src="top.html" frameborder="NO" scrolling="NO" name="top">
    <FRAME src="blank.html" scrolling="NO">
  </FRAMESET>
  <FRAMESET cols="159,*" rows="*" border="0" framespacing="0"> 
    <FRAMESET rows="580,*">

      <FRAME src="left.html" name="left" frameborder="NO" scrolling="NO">
      <FRAME src="blank.html" scrolling="NO">
    </FRAMESET>
    <FRAMESET cols="640,*" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO"> 
      <FRAME src="front.html" frameborder="NO" scrolling="AUTO" name="front">
      <FRAME src="blank.html" name="" scrolling="NO" frameborder="NO">
    </FRAMESET>
  </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
<NOFRAMES><BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

</BODY></NOFRAMES>

</HTML>
```

So question is not how to redesign but how to keep the layout intact while adding editability to pages. I thought that migrating to wordpress could be a good solution but I found I had to migrate a frames site to just a CSS with wordpress which might be doable with the right template or if I make my own template. The CSS I could start for wordpress is

```
body {
background-image:url('http://www.eddaconsult.se/top_files/top.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left top;
}

#page {
background-image:url('http://www.eddaconsult.se/left_files/left.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left top;
}
```

And of course the components don't align like they should since my CSS knowledge is too limited. This is how it looks with my CSS and wordpress:

[image]

Here's the original version of the site where you had to use FTP and manually edit static HTML (the screenshot is a copy of the site I moved to appspot and we are also evaluating appspot as a provider for this project):
[image]
So the goal is very clear and if I can achieve it with wordpress I think it will be better than appspot since the user (a management consultant) doesn't want a new design and doesn't want new hosting, just a more convenient way than FTP and HTML to update the pages and therefore I thought of wordpress. Can you help me align the componenets with CSS or make me some other recommendation? The link to the original site is [here](http://www.eddaconsult.se) and it's OK to keep very old design like no CSS and frames as solution even though I should update the pages to use CSS anyhow what's important is the "blog function" that there is some wysiwyg editor for the pages that should be editable.

I've also deployed a third prototype test via coderbuddy-com but that's not ideal since the solution depends on coderbuddy.com

Do you think wordpress is the best choice for this project? If so, must we make our own template with a template making program such as Artisteer or can we make it with common templates + custom CSS that I bought?

The original site is eddaconsult.se and my prototype building is eddaconsult.com

Any other thoughts/comments/recommendations/answer related to this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No doubt this could be done in Wordpress, but you'll need at least some basic CSS skills (or hire someone) - it's pretty easy to put that into a custom WP template. But seriously - you really want to put your time in migrating an awful website like this?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I agree the site itself is uninteresting, I just see the technical challenge in adding the editability. And it's good for me to know and learn how wordpress is used for instance I think I must host it myself if it's put into a custom WP template(?)

Comment: Best option would be to install a self-hosted WP installation, and then start working on a custom template - you'll need basic PHP+CSS skills for that (and a fair amount of time, though the learning curve is not so steep, and documentation excellent). But still - if you're going through this process - I'd start by reviewing the current site layout and structure - even apart from the horrific design it is an awful, awful website...

Comment: @ptriek thank you for the further elaboration. Of course bad design from the beginning and even worse that the strcture for the manu ssytem is not logical since there are two "menus" so you are right that completely abandoning the old site and just keep the texts for a standard WP theme also should work but the decion-maker doesn't wan't too much change at once, just very little increments and just adding editability to plain text is basically what could fulfil the requirement and then we can forget about the site for another 20 years or forever when the manager has something like a blog / CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this site is so small and simple, I would recommend converting the frames to standard html/css and using a third party CMS like [pagelime](http://pagelime.com) or [CushyCMS](http://CushyCMS.com). this would take the least amount of time for converting this ancient looking site.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree it's a good idea to get rid of the frames.